# How to call function from another class file in php

Tags: php, wamp

I have a Response.php file which has a function inside and i want to call the function to another .php file.

here's the Response.php

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';
$response = array();
class Response_Function{
 public function fieldMissing() {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";
    $response = json_encode($response);

    echo $response;
    }
}

?>
```

and this is the file calling the `fieldMissing()` function

```
<?php
include 'connection';
require_once 'include/Response.php';
$db = new Response_Function();
$response = $db->fieldMissing();
echo $response;
?>
```

Comment: What's wrong - happening now vs what you want to happen? Though I think inside the definition of fieldMissing() you might want `return $response;` instead of `echo $response;`, because as it is the function doesn't return anything. Therefore, in the second file $response will have no useful value assigned to it.

Comment: what do you nean and??

Comment: i want to call the fieldMissing function. how will i call it

Comment: You are already calling it!

Comment: but there's no response appear ..

Comment: Checked for something interesting in logs?

Answer (score 2):

Like BrianDHall said, in your function you need to replace `echo` with `return`

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't echo in a function always use return instead and let the caller echo wherever it needs.

Response.php

```
    <?php

    include 'connection.php';

    class Response_Function
    {

        public $response;

        public function fieldMissing() {

            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

            $this->response = json_encode($response);

    }
}
```

file calling the function fieldMissing()

```
   <?php

   include 'connection';
   require_once 'include/Response.php';

   $db = new Response_Function();
   $db->fieldMissing(); 

   $response = json_decode($db->response);

   echo $response->message;

  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code:

1) The response array should be declared INSIDE the function (however if you need to access it from elsewhere in the class, declare it and use it as a class attribute INSIDE the class);

2) As others have pointed out, the last instruction of your function should be returning the value instead of printing it.

To summarize, your Response.php file should look like this:

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';
class Response_Function{
  public function fieldMissing() {
    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";
    $response = json_encode($response);

    return $response;
  }
}
```